# Using solrj library

Tags: java, solrj

I'm trying to use solrj library in order to do some indexing work on my Cloudera Sorl server.

At this point

```
        String zkHostString = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/solr";
        CloudSolrClient solr = new CloudSolrClient(zkHostString);
```

I got error

```
> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
> SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation SLF4J:
> See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further
```

File slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar exists in my library path (I got all jar files from /dist and /dist/solrj-lib)

To build my project I'm using Eclipse if it doues matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you have old version of slf4j in your classpath, that came from a transitive dependency. Try to check this and then run dependency tree or any other tool to find and resolve the conflicts.